# Is it required to generate a key again to build an app-bundle for a published app on the Play store?

Tags: android, flutter, build, android-app-bundle

We have a flutter application uploaded to the Play store and published properly.

A vendor created it and there's no key file under Android folder when they provided the source codes.

Now, we made some updates to the app and needed to upload the app bundle to the Play store again. (For iOS, there's no issue in uploading to Test flight)

At this point, do we need to create a key store again?

Comment: Who ever wrote the code for the first time or later pushed any updates to the playstore they may have the key file in their project, have you tried asking the vendor for the key file?

Comment: thanks for your comment. we've got the key files from the vendor finally.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to contact Google Support Team for further help.

Losing the key file is bad in terms of user trust and security and you must back it up in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If the Releases is signed by google play, you can contact the google support team and generate a new key file by following the instructions.

[image: If the Releases is signed by google play, you can contact the google support team and generate a new key file by following the instructions.]